# declare function type in function definition in haskell

Tags: haskell

I just began to learn haskell recently. I have some confusion of declare function type in the function definition. For example if we want to define a foldr function:

```
foldr :: (a->b->b)->b->[a]->b
foldr f v [] = v
foldr f v (x:xs) = f x (foldr f v xs)
```

Thus,  foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3,4] = sum [1,2,3,4] = 10.

My question is: can I just change it to something like :

```
foldr :: (a->a->a)->a->[a]->a
 OR:
foldr :: (a->b->c)->x->[y]->z
```

I didn't find a place to explain the choice/requirements of letters in the definition. Thanks!

---

Update:
I tested it with:

```
 foldr :: (a->b->c)->x->[y]->z
```

Got the following err:

```
   Couldn't match type `y' with `a'
  `y' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for folderr :: (a -> b -> c) -> x -> [y] -> z
      at test.hs:3:1
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for folderr :: (a -> b -> c) -> x -> [y] -> z
      at test.hs:3:1
```

If changed everything to a, it works. I must have missing some points here.

---

As explained in @sepp2k's comments. I tested using the following simple example:

```
     folderr :: (a->b->b)->b->[a]->b
     folderr f v [] = v
     folderr f v (x:xs) = f x (folderr f v xs)


     myop :: Int -> Bool -> Bool
     myop x y | x > 0 = True && y
              | otherwise = False && y
```

folderr (myop) True [3,3,222]   -> True
folderr (myop) True [3,2,-1] -> False

So a,b just means the types are different or not.

Comment: If you replaced both of the `a`s with `y`, it would work. But by calling one `a` and the other `y`, you're saying that they can be different. But then the definition of the function treats them as the same, so you get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific names of your type variables do not matter, that is the types `a -> b -> c`, `x -> y -> z` and `foo -> bar -> baz` are all completely equivalent.

What does matter is whether you use the same type variable multiple times or you use different ones. That is `a -> b` is a different type than `a -> a`. Specifically `a -> b` is more general because out of the concrete types `Int -> Int`, `String -> String`, `Int -> String` and `String -> Int`, `a -> a` would only match the first two (with `a = Int` and `a = String` respectively) whereas `a -> b` would match all four.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense to me now. I just tested it using an example.